# Characterizations for SSH and SCH above an uncountable cardinal

Tags: set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic

SSH asserts that pp$(\lambda) =\lambda^+$ for every singular cardinal $\lambda$. There are two nice characterizations for SCH and SCH in terms of covering numbers (see for example "Large cardinals and covering numbers", P. Matet). More specifically, SSH is equivalent to 1. and 2. below:

1. Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be cardinals such that $\mu$ is regular and $\lambda\geq\mu$. Then cf$([\lambda]^{<\mu},\subseteq)=\theta$, where $\theta$ equals $\lambda$ if cf$(\lambda)\geq\mu$, and $\lambda^+$ otherwise;
2. For every singular $\lambda$ of cofinality $\omega$, cf$([\lambda]^{<\omega_1},\subseteq)\leq\lambda^+$,

while SCH is equivalent to 3. and 4. below:

3. Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be cardinals $>\omega$ such that $\mu$ is regular and $\lambda\geq\mu+(\theta(\omega,2^{\aleph_0},\mu))^{++}$. Then cf$([\lambda]^{<\mu},\subseteq)=\theta$, where $\theta$ equals $\lambda$ if cf$(\lambda)\geq\mu$, and $\lambda^+$ otherwise;
4. For every singular $\lambda\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ of cofinality $\omega$, cf$([\lambda]^{<\omega_1},\subseteq)\leq\lambda^+$.

$\theta(\omega,2^{\aleph_0},\mu)$ denotes the least cardinal $\theta\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ such that cf$([\theta]^{<\rho^+},\subseteq)\leq\theta^{++}$ for every infinite cardinal $\rho<\theta\cap\mu$.

I wonder whether it is possible to have similar characterizations for SSH and SCH above a fixed cardinal $\kappa>\omega$. Namely, is it true that conditions 1. and 2. (resp. 3. and 4.) restricted to sufficiently large cardinals $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are equivalent to SSH (resp. SCH) above $\kappa$?

Comment: The relationship between (1) and (2) above a fixed cardinal was briefly studied. Search for "buffer cardinal" in the following paper: https://www.assafrinot.com/paper/01